# Damped sinusoidal motion with initial velocity or acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spring, oscillators

I am looking for the equation of damped sinusoidal motion with an initial velocity.

For example: a mass is moving by `spring1` force. At `t0` `spring1` is removed and `spring2` is suddenly connected on the opposite side (without stopping the mass). Obviously, the mass doesn't just instantly reverse. It would continue in the direction of `spring1` until the force of `spring2` has stopped it (I assume?) and continued it in the other direction.

Comment: Why do you say this is damped motion?  damping is a technical term. Write the general oscillation equation with undertermined coefficients and put in your initial conditions.  There's not special trick or equation.  And this looks an awful lot like a homework problem.

Comment: @BillN I assure you, this is not a homework question. This is something I was thinking about to estimate a particular phenomena (which would definitely be damped). It's been a long time since I've thought about springs and I seem to be a bit rusty. Feel free to point me to a good resource.

Comment: @BillN I would appreciate a resource if you're going to discount the question. If you think it's a homework problem, please provide a link to an example problem. It's not very helpful to tag it as `homework-and-exercises` without giving a resource. Every resource I have found assumes zero initial conditions (easy) or a driven oscillator.

Comment: If you have zero initial conditions, then it doesn't move.  At least one of the conditions ($x(t_0)$ or $v(t_0)$) must be non-zero.  And switching springs simply means that you match the $x$ and $v$ values, as you state at the end of your own answer.  I'm still puzzled as to why you want damped motion, unless you left the damping context out of your original.  The new spring is *not* a traditional damping force. Damping continually removes mechanical energy from the system. A spring does not.

Comment: @BillN I probably should have been clear. In my context, I have some data that looks like damped sinusoidal motion (exponential curve with little overshoot). I was hoping to predict some scenarios (on/off behavior) using damped sinusoidal motion equations. The answer I provided was able to guide me to the solution I needed in my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly more algebraic than I expected.

$$
\lambda_n^+=\frac{-c_n+\sqrt{m_n^2-4c_nk_n}}{2m_n}
$$
$$
\lambda_n^-=\frac{-c_n-\sqrt{m_n^2-4c_nk_n}}{2m_n}
$$

Where `c`,`k`, and `m` are the damping coefficient, spring constant, and mass (respectively). I assume the mass can change (just because).

$$
X_n(t) = a_n^+e^{\lambda_n^+t} + a_n^-e^{\lambda_n^-t}+x_n^0
$$

$$
X_n^\prime(t) = a_n^+\lambda_n^+e^{\lambda_n^+t} + a_n^-\lambda_n^-e^{\lambda_n^-t}
$$

Where $x_n^0$ is the equilibrium location of spring `n`.

Knowing the initial conditions (or at $t_0$),

$$
a_n^+ = \frac{X_n^\prime(0)-\lambda_n^-X_n(0)+x_n^0\lambda_n^-}{\lambda_n^+-\lambda_n^-}
$$
$$
a_n^-=X_n(0)-a_n^--x_n^0
$$

In my case:

$$
X_1(t_0) = X_2(0)
$$
$$
X_1^\prime(t_0) = X_2^\prime(0)
$$

Answer (score 1):

You solve problems like this by writing down the equation of motion. In this case it's just a mass on a spring (i.e. spring 2) so the EQN is:

$$ \frac{d^2x}{dx^2} = -kx $$

where $x$ is the distance from the euilibrium position of spring 2 and $k$ is the force constant of spring 2. Solve this equation then use the initial condition:

$$ v(x_0, t_0) = u $$

where $u$ is the velocity at the moment you disconnected spring 1 and connected spring 2.

The more experienced physicist will note that you don't need to grind through the maths because we know the EQM for a mass on a spring.

$$ x = A\,\sin\left(t\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} + \phi\right) $$

where $A$ and $\phi$ are constants. You just need to use the initial conditions $x(t_0)$ and $v(t_0)$ to find the constants $A$ and $\phi$.